# Unioning Two Tables With Different Number Of Columns in Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark

How do I union two dataframes A and B, containing different number of columns and get nulls for columns that are not common in dataframes A and B?

I can see that spark's `unionAll` doesn't support this action and throws following error

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the left table has 11 columns and the right has 10;`

Spark version: 1.6.1

Comment: I don't know of any DBMS where that query would work fine with different column structures on the unioned tables.

Comment: @Siyual Thanks for the input. Corrected accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query so it specifies all the columns and using `null as missing_field` to compensate for column you don't have

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM A UNION ALL SELECT field1, field2, null as field3 FROM B
```

Comment: Is there an automated way in which I can avoid inspection of columns individually to identify non-common columns?

Comment: you might try select * from a union all select *, null as field3 from B , but I'm not sure if that would work in your configuration.